# OS doesn't auto-detect usb stick(Kingston dt rubber 3.0 32GB)

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

I had an USB pendrive plugged in the laptop when the laptop froze. After that time I can't access my USB pendrive. It doesn't work on other computers either.

I checked disk management and it says "*no medium*".

[image: Disk Management Screenshot]

I have checked drive letter, NOT the problem.
I have re-installed the drivers, NOT the problem.

My other usb still works on my laptop so not broken usb ports.

Comment: He says its not working on other computers - are you sure it works at all? With your problem it seems you cant even format it...

Comment: If you can see it in Disk Management, please provide a screenshot.

Comment: Does "on other computers" include non-Windows machines? Could be some nasty autorun (from vendor-specific "gift" to virus). Did you try to disable autorun on any of the computers you tried it?

Comment: Your statement that "it can't be a virus because I'm the only one using this computer" tells us a lot.

Comment: Prime suspect is you triggered the firmware protect. Throw it away, they're not worth the effort once that happens.

Comment: I meant that everything since win xp carries its own drivers capable of doing it. Otherwise google the vendor and model of the thing to see if by chance they need some exotic installation which is doubtful. By now i would have thrown it back to the vendor to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recapping your points:

- The failing (broken) pendrive does not work on *any* computer.
- When inserted it detects 'something'. (A state similar to inserting a USB floppy drive without floppy inserted, or a SDcard reader without card).

Likely conclusion: It is broken. Either physically or your laptop has other issues and it scambled the pendrive's firmware.

Neither of which you can trivially fix on your own.  Ditch the pen drive or return it under warranty.

Comment: Sounds trivial, but there might not be easy detectable broken traces. And not everybody knows how to solder.  (I got a 700 Watt solder gun. It must be great for electronics because it has lots of Watts. Right?)

Comment: Ah. I have no idea how Sweden works in that regard. Over here (Netherlands) there is usually a 1 or 2 year warranty from the manufactorer and a lesser period (often half a year) from the shop where you bought it (in which case they may simply trade it and sent RMA the broken one).